# Two different command with the same name

Tags: macos, shell, path, command

In OsX i've 2 programs installed in different path with the same terminal name "scmd". If I put the bin folder of each one into the global path, when I run a terminal and type "scmd" only the first founded will run, and I have no way to run the other.

So I need to change the name of the second executable, like "scmd2". In that way i can type "scmd" to run the first and "scmd2" to run the second.

How can I do?

Thanks a lot, I hope I explained.

Comment: If you write the full path of the second one, that one will be executed. So for example if you `which scmd -a` returns `/bin/scmd` and `/usr/bin/scmd`, to run the second use `/usr/bin/scmd`.

Comment: Yeah but the path is not so easy. If possible i really prefer to two global cmds

Answer (score 3):

Create an alias:

```
alias scmd2=/path/of/second/binary
```

To have it permanent, store it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

You can see all the paths for that binary with:

```
which scmd -a
```